# NSString to const void *

Tags: objective-c

How to convert NSString to const void?

I've tried

```
NSString *testString = @"testString";
const void *testConstVoid = CFBridgingRetain(testString);
```

But testConstVoid is still an nsstring

Comment: What do you mean by `testConstVoid` is still an `NSString`? Would you like your `const void*` to point to something in particular?

Comment: In debug mode, testConstVoid  is still a NSString. Currently the library is using this  const void* license ="Y:xxx" . However, I'm accepting NSString from user and I would like to convert this NSString to const void *. so that i can pass it to the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `CFBridgingRetain(testString)`, you should use `testString.UTF8String`

```
NSString *testString = @"testString";
const void *testConstVoid = testString.UTF8String;
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [`UTF8String`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411189-utf8string?language=objc) you have [`cStringUsingEncoding:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1408489-cstringusingencoding?language=objc) and [`getCString:maxLength:encoding:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1415702-getcstring?language=objc).

In the first 2 cases you need to copy the returned C string to your own char buffer or `NSData` if you plan to use it past the original `NSString` lifetime:

```
NSString *str = @"hello";
const char *cStr = str.UTF8String;
const NSUInteger cStrLen = [str lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableData *cStrData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithBytes:cStr
                                                        length:cStrLen + 1];
    // +1 for '\0' (C string null-terminator)
const void *cStrBytes = cStrData.bytes;
```